# Failed to show Default Images when passed imagename is not found in assets in Android?

Tags: java, android, bitmap, imageview

Here is my code i have written to get images from assets folder by passing imagename from database.But when passedImage name is not found in assets folder then i want to show some dummy images my code is throwing only catch block when no image is found but its not showing default image and no log is print in case of image not found .....

```
private Bitmap getBitmapFromAsset(String strName) {
    AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
    InputStream istr = null;
    Bitmap bitmap = null;

    try {
        istr = assetManager.open(strName);
        if(istr.equals("null"))
        {
            Log.i("getBitmapFromAsset isStr",""+istr);
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(assetManager.open("save_fatwa.jpg"));
        }
        else
        {
             bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(istr);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.i("getBitmapFromAsset",""+bitmap);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return bitmap;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

AssetManager.open returns an InputStream, not a string.  If should be `if(istr==null)` not if it equals the string "null".